# Can we recover a sheaf from its original presheaf on a basis

Tags: sheaf-theory

This question might be completely totological (I apologize in advance if it is the case):

suppose that we are given two sheaves $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ of Abelian groups on a topological space $X$, and denote by $F, G$ their underlying respective presheaves (that is their images via the inclusion functor $Sh(X) \hookrightarrow Psh(X)$). 
Suppose that $F$ and $G$ agree on a basis of topology. Does this imply that the sheaves agree ?

I know that, in general, the data of a presheaf on a basis doesn’t suffice to recover the sheaf, but here it is the presheaf coming from a sheaf, so I have somehow the feeling that it is different. Am I missing something ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: See EGA 0$_{\rm I}$.3.2.5 (1971 edition).

Answer (score 3):

To ensure that the two sheaves are the same, we need that not only the sections of the sheaves on the elements of a basis but also restriction maps between them to be identical. If this is the case,  two sheaves are identical.
I guess the notion of B-sheaves(remark 2.6 on the page 36) in the book of Qing-Liu will be helpful. (B denotes a basis)

Comment: I think there is a similar notion in Vakil's notes

Comment: Thanks @Gualterio for your answer. Is there a proof of your statement somewhere ?

Comment: I'm sorry that I don't know how to use latex. Suppose F is a sheaf on X and B is a basis of X such that for any elements U, U' of B, F(U)=G(U)=H(U), restriction map from F(U) to F(U') is the same as the restriction map from G(U) to G(U') and so on. (In general, the sheafification of a presheaf takes two steps; first we take the quotient presheaf by killing sections of the original presheaf that becomes zero at stalks. Then we glue local sections of the quotient presheaf to a global one. In this case if G, H are sheaves on a basis, we just need to take the second step)

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your argument. Suppose that $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are sheaves on $X$. Suppose that the associated presheaves $F$ and $G$ agree on a basis $\mathcal{B}$, and that for any $U \subset V \in \mathcal{B}$, the restriction morphisms $\text{res}_{V,U}^F = \text{res}_{V,U}^G$, where $\text{res}_{V,U}$ are restriction morphisms with obvious notations.

How to prove that $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{G}$ ?

Comment: For any open subset W of X, a section of F on W is uniquely represented by its restrictions to some subset of elements of B say {U_i} such that {U_i}s cover W. We can give an equivalence relation to these representations (by the definition we can take refinements) to make the equivalence classes into an abelian group. This is the same as interpreting F(W) as the set of functions on W into the disjoint union of stalks satisfying the local condition. I'm sorry that my explanation is bad.

Comment: The global sections of F and G on {U_i}s are canonically identified respecting the gluing conditions. That means as groups the set of global sections of F and G on arbitrary open subset W can be identified.

Comment: By the equivalence of representation of a section. Let me give an example. Suppose {U_i} and {V_j} are subsets of a basis B that are open coverings of W. Let s_i be a section of F on U_i such that {s_i} satisfies the gluing conditions (For any element of basis U'' inside the intersection of U_i and U_i' the restrictions of s_i, s_i' to U'' are the same) I define (s_i), (t_j) to be equivalent if (s_i) and (t_j) satisfies the gluing condition. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2):

See theorem 2.5.1 [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf). I claim that a sheaf of sets $F$ on a topological space $X$ with base $B_i$ ($i \in I$) is determined uniquely by the data of sets $F(B_i)$ ($i \in I$) and maps $\mathrm{res}_{B_i, B_j}:F(B_i)\rightarrow F(B_j)$ for all $i, j\in I$ such that $B_j \subset B_i$. To see why this is true, consider following presheaf of sets
$$
\mathcal{F}(U)=\{(f_p\in F_p)_{p \in U}|\mathrm{for}\:\mathrm{all}\:p\in U, \: \mathrm{there}\:\mathrm{exists} \: B\:\mathrm{with}\:p\in B\subset U, s \in F(B), \:\mathrm{with}\: s_q=f_q \: \mathrm{for}\:\mathrm{all} \:q \in B\}.
$$ 
where $B$ is some element of the base. It's trivial to verify that $\mathcal{F}$ is actually a sheaf of sets. Moreover, the map of sheaf $F\rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ given by talking stalks is an isomorphism (injectivity follows from identity axiom, surjectivity from gluability axiom).

So, to answer the original question. Let $F, G$ be sheaves of sets on a topological space $X$ with base $B_i$ ($i \in I$). Assume that we have an isomorphism $F(B_i)\rightarrow G(B_i)$ for every $B_i$ ($i\in I$). Then $F$ and $G$ are isomorphic as sheaves of sets iff the diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
    F(B_i) @>>> G(B_i)\\
    @V \mathrm{res}_{B_i, B_j} V V @VV \mathrm{res}_{B_i, B_j} V\\
    F(B_j) @>>> G(B_j)
\end{CD}
is commutative for all $i, j \in I$ such that $B_j \subset B_i$.